# Use username from table "Account" to get the values of the table "Location" SQL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, mdf

Here's my code on making an account and the values on the comments

```
"INSERT INTO Accounts VALUES('"+
                        txtuser.Text + "','" + txtpass.Text +"')"+

"INSERT INTO Location VALUES('" +
                        txtcity.Text + "','" + txtprovince.Text + "','" + txtcountry.Text + "')"

//txtuser.Text = "Dory"
//txtpass.Text = "FINDME!"
//txtcity.Text = "Ermita"
//txtprovince.Text = "Manila"
//txtcountry.Text = "Philippines"
```

***PROBLEM***
How do i get the values of the table ***Location*** by basing the value of user on table Accounts?
For example:
***DORY location is Ermita,Manila,Phillipines***

My sql code here is not working

```
SELECT *
FROM Accounts,
     Email
WHERE Accounts.username = 'Dory'
```

But my code does not work properly

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: I see no foreign key from Location to Accounts. It looks that you have two separate tables, with no links between them.

Comment: How do i fix my problem?

Comment: Hi s3cr3t, you need to have something linking the to tables Accounts and Location. In your table Account, when you creata a user, a key (new column) is created. That key is also added to the location informations of the Location of the user. Now with that key data from accounts can be lined with data from Location

Comment: show us your tables structure.

Comment: what do you mean by tables structure VDN? sorry im new on SQL

Comment: Join tables with id,    

SELECT ac.*
FROM Accounts ac
left join Location lc on ac.username=lc.username
WHERE ac.username like '%Dory%'